# Why is no data found after calling SqlDataReader.NextResult?

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatareader

My problem is that this does not work;

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   if (reader.NextResult() == true)
   {
      json.AppendFormat("{{\"AvgDate\": \"{0}\"}},{{\"MarkerID\": \"{1}\"}},", reader["AvgDate"], reader["MarkerID"]);
   }
```

But this works;

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    json.AppendFormat("{{\"AvgDate\": \"{0}\"}},{{\"MarkerID\": \"{1}\"}},", reader["AvgDate"], reader["MarkerID"]);
}
```

The problem with the first one is that the reader doesn't find any data to read. I get;

> "Invalid attempt to read when no data
>   is present."

Can anyone see why?

Comment: Please change the title of this question to a question. "SqlDataReader problem" is extremely uninformative. How about "Why is no data found after calling SqlDataReader.NextResult?" or similar?

Comment: @KennyEvitt What is the original question if you remember? Good call to make it more search friendly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NextResult() makes the reader advance to the next result set coming back from the query.  The way you have it written, it would skip the first result set (likely the only one).

The pattern I think you want is:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
     do
     {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             ...
        }
     }
     while (reader.NextResult());
}
```

This will check if there are any results, and if so, read the results in each result set until there are no more left to read.

**EDIT**: Based on comment:

For JSON, consider using a list of temporary objects, then a DataContractJsonSerializer:

```
 public class DateClass
 {
      public string AvgDate { get; set; }
      public int MarkerID { get; set; }
 }

 ...

 var dates = new List<DateClass>();
 if (reader.HasRows)
 {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
           var date = new DateClass { AvgDate = reader["AvgDate"].ToString(), MarkerID = (int)reader["MarkerID"] };
            dates.Add( date );
       }
 }

 var stream = new MemoryStream();
 var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof(DateClass) );
 serializer.WriteObject( stream, dates );
 stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
 return stream.ToString();
```

Comment: +1.  Clarifying, a "resultset" can be thought of as a table.  NextResult() is only necessary when your SQL statement returns multiple tables.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That explains things. However there is no HasResults method for this class. Any suggestion on how to proceed without one? I can't find any useful method actually, but maybe I'm overlooking something

Comment: @cc0 - Yea the correct function is reader.HasRows() not HasResults(). It tells you if your resultset returned any rows or not. If no rows are returned and you do a reader.Read() you will get an exception, so always have to check for reader.HasRows() before calling the reader.Read() function.

Comment: @jaywon - nice catch.  It's been awhile since I've used SqlDataReader and I neglected to look it up when typing my answer.  It' also a property, not a method.  So much for my memory.

Comment: Ah, thanks guys, this clarifies things. However what I'm trying to do is avoid that a comma is added at the end, when the final reader entry is printed. I'm still not sure how to accomplish that. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll add an idea on how to do that.

Comment: @tv - oops. yes you are correct HasRows is a property. i also did not look it up. don't feel so bad tho knowing the big dogs still make the same mistakes. homer simpson effect :p

Comment: Lol, well anyway. Just to add what I figured out here on how to simply remove the last part of a string. *drum roll* TrimEnd()! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

NextResult takes you to the next Result Set from the Reader.  You probably only have one Result Set.

Answer (score 4):

the code from tvanfosson's answer above:

```
if (reader.HasRows) 
{
     do
     {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
         ...
        }
     }
     while (reader.NextResult());
}
```

should instead be:

```
do
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
} while (reader.NextResult());
```

There may be result sets without rows that would cause the previous code example to throw an exception.  Worse, the first result set may have no rows, and the later result sets would then not be read.

But thanks for letting me know why and how HasRows is used.